# How to debug Tomcat source code with an application which uses embedded tomcat server?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, ant

I am working with a full-stack application(JSP and Java,Spring based). It is having an **embedded tomcat server**. Suppose I made some changes in the ***tomcat source code*** relevant to the embedded tomcat server(same tomcat version) which I use in my application.

I need to **debug the tomcat source code** *when upping my application with the embedded tomcat server*.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Note: I use Apache ANT as the build tool.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you need to substitute the jar file with embedded tomcat (I guess this is `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core`). Please follow these steps:

1. First of all you need to build the jar from sources that you've modified locally by running e.g. `mvn clean install`. This would install the jar built locally into your local maven repository. Pay attention, that in order to distinguish your build from the rest you need to specify your custom version in pom.xml of Tomcat sources (e.g. you specify `9.0.0-my-custom-build`)
2. As soon as your custom build is now in m2 it can be used by your main application. In `<dependencyManagement>` section of your pom.xml you need to specify this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.0-my-custom-build</version>
</dependency>
```

This declaration forces maven to use tomcat of your custom version i. e. `9.0.0-my-custom-build`.

3. Build your application and run it. At debug time you'll be able to see and debug your changes.

P.S. No matter what is your building system, the clue is the same: jar built from modified sources must substitute the default one in classpath of your application.